# How to find short mystery stories not whodunit or supernatural?

Tags: teaching

I am teaching my student in Japan- she is quite advanced and has lived in England for 3 years but she is 8 years old - and she like mystery stories. I can find many stories that start with a crime- and so far she likes what I have found but I would like more choices. Examples are Jonathan Creek, some Biggles stories. What should I search for? Her supernatural preferences are probably too specific to find examples such as Chinese zombies.

Comment: There is a series "Sam the cat mysteries" by Linda Stewart. Sam is a cat and he is a detective. I'm not sure about the age limit (but then I don't know if many mystery stories are written for 8-year olds; you can probably  check about this one on-line). I've read one of those ages ago, and I loved it. I hope that helps at least bit :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I don't paid enough to buy books but the client is  rich enough to get it for the child and sister- they have and buy a lot of books.

Comment: You're welcome. What I thought was that you could recommend books for your student (it definitely shouldn't be your responsibility to buy them, it's quite nice of you to even ask around for something she might like). I googled Biggles stories and found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biggles) is that what your were referring to?

Comment: The website GoodReads.com is a nice resource to get recommendations on all types of books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nancy Drew is a good series for young readers. Hardy Boys is very similar in style (with the stories about 2 boys rather than a lone girl). Those are both novel-length series. Encyclopedia Brown would be shorter stories. I read a lot of the books from those three series as a child.

Answer (score 0):

"Encyclopedia Brown" stories would be great for an 8-year-old -- they are short and can be solved with a little thinking and logic.